# TypeScript newable and enum reference

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, enums, typescript-typings

I have an external SDK written in JavaScript which I am using. One of these modules, `Blob` is new-able, but also exposes an enum `FooEnum` (members `Bar` and `Baz`).

The code for using this SDK in JavaScript is like so:

```
const blobInstance = new Sdk.Blob();
const fooType = Sdk.Blob.FooEnum.Baz;
```

I am now trying to write an interface that I can cast this SDK to in order to give me some type safety. Here is what I've got so far:

```
interface BlobInterface { }

enum Foo {
    Bar,
    Baz
}

interface Sdk {
    Blob: {
        new(): BlobInterface;
        FooEnum: Foo;
    }
}
```

My problem, however, is that when I reference `Blob.FooEnum`, it thinks that `FooEnum` itself is actually a member of the enum `Foo` (i.e. it believes that it is `Bar` or `Baz`) and, therefore, doesn't let me get `Baz` from it.

How can I tell TypeScript that `Blob.FooEnum` actually points to the enum itself and isn't a member of the enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Foo` is both a value name and a type name.  As a value, it represents the object whose properties have keys `Bar` and `Baz` and whose values are `0` and `1`, respectively (it also has properties with keys `0` and `1` whose values are `"Bar"` and `"Baz"`, respectively.).  As a type, it represents the union of types of `Foo.Bar` and `Foo.Baz`. These are not the same: the value `Foo` is not of type `Foo`.

This is like in a class (e.g., `class Bar {}`), where the value `Bar` represents the class constructor, and the type `Bar` represents the type of an instance of the class.  Again, the value `Bar` is not of type `Bar`.

In both cases, if you want the type corresponding to the value with the name `Foo` or `Bar`, you use `typeof` with the value:

```
interface Sdk {
    Blob: {
        FooEnum: typeof Foo;
    }
}
```

Now `FooEnum` has the same type as the object `Foo`, and it should work for you.

Good luck!